# Adding Styles on first 5 elements after clicking button using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [html](/questions/tagged/html) codes like this

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="button hide">1</div>
    <div class="button hide">2</div>
    <div class="button hide">3</div>
    <div class="button hide">4</div>
    <div class="button hide">5</div>
    <div class="button hide">6</div>
    <div class="button hide">7</div>
 ..........
</div>
<a href="#" class="input">ZZZ</a>
```

I want to add style `display:block` to first five buttons (1,2,3,4,5 in this case) after clicking `ZZZ` And again if i click button ZZZ i want to hide first 5 buttons and add style `display:block` to 6,7,8,9,10

I could think up to here but we know style applies to all elements . Is it possible to add it for only first five buttons ?

```
$(".input").click(function(){
    $(.button).css("display","block");
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If you want to access certain divs specifically then add a separate class for them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) pseudo-selector to select first `n` elements.

> Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

```js
$('.input').on('click', function() {
  $('.button:lt(5)').removeClass('hide');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="button hide">1</div>
  <div class="button hide">2</div>
  <div class="button hide">3</div>
  <div class="button hide">4</div>
  <div class="button hide">5</div>
  <div class="button hide">6</div>
  <div class="button hide">7</div>
  ..........
</div>
<a href="#" class="input">ZZZ</a>
```

**EDIT**

To select elements after `5`th index, you can use [`:gt`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) pseudo-selector.

> Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

```js
$('.input').on('click', function() {
  $('.button:gt(4)').removeClass('hide');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="button hide">1</div>
  <div class="button hide">2</div>
  <div class="button hide">3</div>
  <div class="button hide">4</div>
  <div class="button hide">5</div>
  <div class="button hide">6</div>
  <div class="button hide">7</div>
  ..........
</div>
<a href="#" class="input">ZZZ</a>
```

Comment: thanks but i modified a little . And again if i click button ZZZ i want to hide first 5 buttons and add style `display:block` to 6,7,8,9,10 . Can we do in this question or i should consider asking another one?

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d5wLxvca/3/)

```
$(".input").click(function(){
    $('.main').find('.notblock').css("display","none");
});
```

`html`

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="button hide">1</div>
 <div class="button hide">2</div>
 <div class="button hide">3</div>
 <div class="button hide">4</div>
 <div class="button hide">5</div>
 <div class="button hide notblock">6</div>
 <div class="button hide notblock">7</div>
 ..........
</div>
<a href="#" class="input">ZZZ</a>
```

Add class to the div you want to be left out of selection and then use that class to select them to be left out. In this sample i added notblock to 6 and 7 div then using that class to select them to add a display none to them

`UPDATE`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d5wLxvca/4/)

```
$(".input").click(function () {
    $('.main').find('.notblock').toggle();
    $('.main').find('.hide').toggle();
});
```

`html`

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="button hide">1</div>
    <div class="button hide">2</div>
    <div class="button hide">3</div>
    <div class="button hide">4</div>
    <div class="button hide">5</div>
    <div class="button notblock">6</div>
    <div class="button notblock">7</div>
    <div class="button notblock">8</div>
    <div class="button notblock">9</div>
    <div class="button notblock">10</div>..........</div>
<a href="#" class="input">ZZZ</a>
```

`UPDATE`

As per @Tushar suggestion to shorter the `selector` from `$('.main').find('.notblock').toggle();
    $('.main').find('.hide').toggle();` to `$('.main').find('.notblock, .hide').toggle();`

Comment: `I want to add style display:block to first five button (1,2,3,4,5 in this case) after clicking ZZZ` you're not answering this question, you're changing the propeties of the other elements

Comment: IT is just to show that the 6 and 7 is only the one having the color red same logic but i will change it give me time

Comment: You can use `:not(.notblock)`

Comment: @Tushar i have change the sample i made i didnt use the selector you gave me since i thought i will give a different answer. I mainly revolve my answer on the added class and using that class as selector please feel free to comment on the answer

Comment: You can shorten the code by combining the selectors `$('.main').find('.notblock, .hide').toggle();` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/d5wLxvca/6/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .show() and .hide() function already adding display:block and display:none to the element.

if you need some toggle between first 5 and others:

```
$('.input').on('click', function() {
    if($('.button:eq(0)').is(":visible")){
        $('.button:gt(4)').show();
        $('.button:lt(5)').hide();
    }else{
        $('.button:lt(5)').show();
        $('.button:gt(4)').hide();
    }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Put some words to it.